# Fab Speed Dial md-fab-actions not working with ng-repeat and django {% verbatim%}

Tags: html, css, angularjs, django

***I am trying to use ng-repeat over list of image coming from my controller to show as md-fab-actions which cause actions button always opened or expanded, means mouse click is not working. The commented code of html works fine without ng-repeat, means toggle well on mouse click.***

**Here is the angular code**

```
 (function() {
  'use strict';

  angular.module('fabButtomApp',['ngMaterial', 'ngMessages', 'material.svgAssetsCache'])
    .controller('fabButtomAppController', function($scope, $mdDialog, $timeout) {
      var self = this;

      self.hidden = false;
      self.isOpen = false;
      self.hover = false;

      // On opening, add a delayed property which shows tooltips after the speed dial has opened
      // so that they have the proper position; if closing, immediately hide the tooltips
      $scope.$watch('fabButtonQuick.isOpen', function(isOpen) {
        if (isOpen) {
          $timeout(function() {
            $scope.tooltipVisible = self.isOpen;
          }, 600);
        } else {
          $scope.tooltipVisible = self.isOpen;
        }
      });

      self.items = [
        { name: "Share Blog", icon: 'static/scrumboard/sss/share.svg', direction: "top", class:"md-fab md-raised md-mini share-blog"},
        { name: "Comment", icon: 'static/scrumboard/sss/comment.svg', direction: "top", class:"md-fab md-raised md-mini comment-blog" },
        { name: "Create Blog", icon: 'static/scrumboard/sss/add.svg', direction: "top", class:"md-fab md-raised md-mini create-blog"}
      ];

      self.openDialog = function($event, item) {
        // Show the dialog
        $mdDialog.show({
          clickOutsideToClose: true,
          controller: function($mdDialog) {
            // Save the clicked item
            this.item = item;

            // Setup some handlers
            this.close = function() {
              $mdDialog.cancel();
            };
            this.submit = function() {
              $mdDialog.hide();
            };
          },
          controllerAs: 'dialog',
          templateUrl: 'dialog.html',
          targetEvent: $event
        });
      };
    });
})();
```

## Here is the html code

```
    {% load staticfiles %}

    <div ng-controller="fabButtomAppController as fabButtonQuick" layout="column" class="fabSpeedDialdemoBasicUsage">
        <md-content class="md-padding" layout="column">
            <p>
                You may supply a direction of <code>left</code>, <code>up</code>, <code>down</code>, or
                <code>right</code> through the <code>md-direction</code> attribute.
            </p>

            <div class="lock-size" layout="row" layout-align="center center" ng-cloak>
    <!-- 
                <md-fab-speed-dial class="md-fab-bottom-right md-scale" md-open="false" md-direction="left" ng-class="md-scale">
                    <md-fab-trigger>
                        <md-button aria-label="menu" class="menu-fab-button-icon md-fab md-warn">
                            <md-tooltip>Blog Action</md-tooltip>
                            <md-icon md-svg-src="{% static "scrumboard/sss/menu.svg" %}"></md-icon>
                        </md-button>
                    </md-fab-trigger>

                    <md-fab-actions>
                        <md-button aria-label="plus" class="md-fab md-raised md-mini share-blog">
                            <md-tooltip direction="up" md-visible="tooltipVisible" md-autohide="false">Share</md-tooltip>
                            <md-icon md-svg-src="{% static "scrumboard/sss/share.svg" %}"></md-icon>
                        </md-button>
                        <md-button aria-label="facebook" class="md-fab md-raised md-mini comment-blog">
                            <md-tooltip direction="up" md-visible="sntooltipVisible" md-autohide="false">Comment</md-tooltip>
                            <md-icon md-svg-src="{% static "scrumboard/sss/comment.svg" %}"></md-icon>
                        </md-button>
                        <md-button aria-label="Google hangout" class="md-fab md-raised md-mini create-blog">
                            <md-tooltip direction="up" md-visible="tooltipVisible" md-autohide="false">Crete New Blog</md-tooltip>
                            <md-icon md-svg-src="{% static "scrumboard/sss/add.svg" %}"></md-icon>
                        </md-button>
                    </md-fab-actions>
                </md-fab-speed-dial> 

-->
                <md-fab-speed-dial class="md-fab-bottom-right md-scale" md-open="false" md-direction="left"   ng-class="md-scale}">
                    <md-fab-trigger>
                        <md-button aria-label="menu" class="md-fab md-warn">
                            <md-tooltip md-direction="top" md-visible="tooltipVisible">Menu</md-tooltip>
                            <md-icon md-svg-src="{% static "scrumboard/sss/menu.svg" %}" aria-label="menu"></md-icon>
                        </md-button>
                    </md-fab-trigger>

                    <md-fab-actions>
                        {% verbatim %}
                        <div ng-repeat="item in fabButtonQuick.items">
                            <md-button aria-label="{{item.name}}" class="{{item.class}}" ng-click="fabButtonQuick.openDialog($event, item)">
                                <md-tooltip md-direction="{{item.direction}}" md-visible="tooltipVisible" md-autohide="false">
                                    {{item.name}}
                                </md-tooltip>
                                <md-icon md-svg-src="{{(item.icon)}}" aria-label="{{item.name}}"></md-icon>
                            </md-button>
                        </div>
                        {% endverbatim %}
                    </md-fab-actions>
                </md-fab-speed-dial>
            </div>
        </md-content>
    </div>
```

## Here is the css

```
.fabSpeedDialdemoBasicUsage.md-fab-bottom-right {
  top: auto;
  right: 20px;
  bottom: 20px;
  left: auto;
  position: absolute;
  /*background: blue;*/
}

/*button.md-fab.md-warn.menu-fab-button-icon{
   background-color: black !important;
}*/
.fabSpeedDialdemoBasicUsage.md-button{
  background-color: blue !important;
}
.fabSpeedDialdemoBasicUsage.create-blog{
  background-color: green !important;
}
.fabSpeedDialdemoBasicUsage.comment-blog{
  background-color: red !important;
}
.fabSpeedDialdemoBasicUsage.share-blog{
  background-color: #3a4d5a !important;
}
```

Out: This should be toggled using ng-repeat and verbatim on mouseover or click:
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qPW0e.png)

Comment: Seems to have problem with angular version:

Comment: Working well with following newer version: angular 1.4.8 and angular-material 1.0.0. I was using angular 1.35.8 and angular-material 0.10.0 old version early.